# When is the Quarter 1 Estimated Tax form Due in the US?

Tags: united-states, irs, estimated-taxes

I am new to filing form 1040 ES for estimated taxes; when is this form due? The form itself says April 18th, 2016:

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf

This seems simple enough but I am reading that the estimated tax payment (which I presume goes hand in hand with this form) is due on April 15th, 2016:

https://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/Estimated-Tax/Individuals/Individuals-2

I know there is something simple I am just not getting; my apologies in advance. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: The thing is estimated tax payments are never due early.  If the IRS isn't open on the 15th the due date slips to when they are open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emancipation Day falls on the 16th, but is being observed on the 15th this year. This is observed only in Washington, DC, therefore the IRS is closed on the 15th. This means the next business day is the 18th.

Note that Maine and Massachusetts residents have until the 19th to file because there is a state holiday (Patriot's Day) on April 18th.

[Source](http://www.vox.com/2016/4/12/11408056/taxes-due-later-tax-day-emancipation-day)